# scroll to list item in AlertDialog without selection

Tags: android, scroll, android-alertdialog

I have a huge list of items that I present in an AlertDialog.  I would like to present the user the list scrolled to the most likely area they will select one item from.  I'm using

```
AlertDialog.Builder.setSingleChoiceItems(myAdapter, ...).  
ArrayAdapter<MyType> myAdapter;
```

The problem I'm having a hard time with is how to scroll to an item when it's not logically correct to present the item as selected.

I tried getting the `ListView` from the resulting `AlertDialog`.  But it's empty (even after the `Builder` creates and shows it).
I tried forcing a populated `ListView` by inflating a plane `ListView` in res/layout.  `listView.scrollTo(x, y)` didn't seem to have an effect.
I tried up setting the `OnShowListener` for the AlertDialog.  `onShow`() is never invoked.

Does anyone know of a work around?

Comment: Can you post some of your code for the AlertDialog? I'm a little confused as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: @BenBenard Thanks for trying to help.  I changed my strategy.  I organized a collapsible list.

Comment: I encountered exact the same problem of this. Sadly it seems like there's still no answer to this. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

## You could use the functions which are part of the ListView class:

```
smoothScrollByOffset(int offset);
```

or

```
smoothScrollToPosition(int position);
```

---

**Or**

## if you want to scroll one by one you could use functions like:

```
private void scrollToNext() {
int currentPosition = getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition();
if (currentPosition == getListView().getCount() - 1)
    return;
getListView().setSelection(currentPosition + 1);
getListView().clearFocus();
}

private void scrollToPrevious() {
int currentPosition = getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition();
if (currentPosition == 0)
    return;
getListView().setSelection(currentPosition - 1);
getListView().clearFocus();
}
```

Comment: but how to get the listView from the AlertDialog?  Like I said, when I tried getting the listView from the AlertDialog, it's list was empty.

Comment: You should keep one SO question to one question, else there will be no end. You should check http://android-vogue.blogspot.in/2011/12/android-alert-dialog-with-listview-and.html

Comment: I was trying to clarify your answer to my question.  It's not out of scope.  I stated that the AlertDialog's ListView was empty in the OP.  I don't know where the ListView would be buried.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: @stephen please upvote the answer instead of saying +1 in the answer

Comment: it's not an acceptable answer.  But I appreciate you taking the time to answer.  Hence the +1.